# What are the android sdk changes in android-n preview?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I want to know what are the `android-sdk` changes in `android-n` preview.

Answer (score 2):

They are listed in the release and change notes. Moving to the open jdk and removing private API where the key aspects.

This here might affect you mostly:

> Android N includes namespace changes to prevent loading of non-public APIs. If you use the NDK, you should only be using public APIs from the Android platform. Using non-public APIs in the next official release of Android can cause your app to crash.
>
> In order to alert you to use of non-public APIs, apps running on an Android N device generate an error in logcat output when an app calls a non-public API. This error is also displayed on the device screen as a message to help raise awareness of this situation. You should review your app code to remove use of non-public platform APIs and thoroughly test your apps using a preview device or emulator.
>
> If your app depends on platform libraries, see the NDK documentation for typical fixes for replacing common private APIs with public API equivalents. You may also be linking to platform libraries without realizing it, especially if your app uses a library that is part of the platform (such as libpng), but is not part of the NDK. In that case, ensure that your APK contains all the .so files you intended to link against.
>
> **Caution:** Some third-party libraries may link to non-public APIs. If your app uses these libraries, your app may crash when running on the next official release of Android.
>
> Apps should not depend on or use native libraries that are not included in the NDK, because they may change, or be removed from one Android release to another. The switch from OpenSSL to BoringSSL is an example of such a change. Also, different devices may offer different levels of compatibility, because there are no compatibility requirements for platform libraries not included in the NDK. If you must access non-NDK libraries on older devices, make the loading dependent on the Android API level.

Refs:

- https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html
- https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html

Answer (score 2):

First check [Support and Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html) of **This document highlights what's new for developers.**

Get the N Preview reference documentation download from [here](http://developer.android.com/shareables/preview/n-preview-1-docs.zip) its contain **Android API Differences Report** : This report details the changes in the core Android framework API between two API Level specifications. It shows additions, modifications, and removals for packages, classes, methods, and fields. The report also includes general statistics that characterize the extent and type of the differences.

---

**API Change Statistics**

[image]

---

**EDITED**

**[API Difference](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/24/changes.html)** after final release of **ANDROID 7.0**

Comment: Above links are not working and where can i find this information?

Comment: thanks for the update first link is working but the other is showing xml with no such key.Basically i want the api changes(Package changes,classes changes) as we can see in your screenshot attached.

Answer (score 2):

According to me Android N Main feature is **Multi-window mode:**

Android N adds support for displaying more than one app at the same time. On handheld devices, two apps can run side-by-side or one-above-the-other in split-screen mode.

**Multi-Window Lifecycle:**

Multi-window mode does not change the activity lifecycle.

> Note: In multi-window mode, an app can be in the paused state and still be visible to the user. An app might need to continue its activities even while paused. For example, a video-playing app that is in paused mode but is visible should continue showing its video. For this reason, we recommend that activities that play video not pause the video in their onPause() handlers. Instead, they should pause video in onStop(), and resume playback in onStart().

**ICU4J APIs in Android**

Android N now offers a subset of ICU4J APIs in the Android framework under the android.icu package.

**Permissions Changes:**

1. **GET_ACCOUNTS (Deprecated)**
2. **ACTION_OPEN_EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY** (New)

> Apps can now use the intent ACTION_OPEN_EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY to request
>   that the system create a directory for the app's use.

**Moving to OpenJDK from Java APIs**

Android N moves Android’s Java language libraries to an OpenJDK-based approach, creating a common code base for developers to build apps and services.

Answer (score 1):

Android N key developer features.

- [Multi-window support](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#multi-window_support)
- [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#notification_enhancements)
- [Quick Settings Tile API](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#tile_api)
- [Data Saver](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#data_saver)
- [Locales and languages](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#multi-locale_languages)
- [ICU4J APIs in Android](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#icu4)
- [Android TV recording](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#android_tv_recording)
- [Number-blocking](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#number-blocking)
- [Call screening](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#call_screening)
- [Direct Boot](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#direct_boot)
- [Key Attestation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#key_attestation)
- [Network Security Config](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#network_security_config)
- [Default Trusted CA](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#default_trusted_ca)
- [Scoped directory access](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#scoped_directory_access)
- [Android for Work](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#android_for_work)
- [JIT/AOT compilation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#jit_aot)
- [Quick path to app install](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#quick_path_to_app_install)
- [Doze on the go](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#doze_on_the_go)
- [Background optimizations](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#background_optimizations)
- [OpenGLTM ES 3.2 API](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/api-overview.html#gles_32)

Answer (score 0):

**Android N key developer features.**

**1 Multi-window Support**

**2 Notification Enhancements**

Direct reply: For real-time communication apps, the Android system supports inline replies so that users can quickly respond to an SMS or text message directly within the notification interface.

**3 Quick Path to App Install**

now install in just a matter of seconds. System updates are also faster, since there's no more optimizing step

**4 Doze on the Go...**

**This means users can save battery even when carrying their devices in their pockets.**

When the device is stationary again, with screen off and on battery for a period of time, Doze applies the full CPU and network restrictions on PowerManager.WakeLock, AlarmManager alarms, and GPS/Wi-Fi scans.

**5 Project Svelte: Background Optimizations**

**6 SurfaceView**

**7 Data Saver  Go to setting and Unrestricted data access on**

**8 Vulkan API**

**9 Quick Settings Tile API**

**10 Number Blocking** 
Android 7.0 now supports number blocking in the platform and provides a framework API to let service providers maintain a blocked-number list.

- Numbers blocked on calls are also blocked on texts
- Blocked numbers can persist across resets and devices through the Backup & Restore feature
- Multiple apps can use the same blocked numbers list

**11 Call Screening**

Reject the incoming call

Do not allow the call to the call log

Do not show the user a notification for the call

**12 Multi-locale Support, More Languages**

**13 New Emojis**

**14 ICU4J APIs in Android**

**More Information **

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#icu4